# Convert select Oracle query to support PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

**Oracle Query -**

In Oracle, restrict is of varchar data type with check constraint of json type, and we are trying to get the result where the informationType = 'MEASURE' and accessScope = 'NONE' in the column  value of table.

```
select distinct u_id
from u_restrict u,
json_table(u.restrict, '$[*]' columns (informationType varchar2 path '$.informationType',
accessScope varchar2 path '$.accessScope')) jt 
where jt.informationType = 'MEASURE' and jt.accessScope = 'NONE'
```

**PostgreSQL query-**

In PostgreSQL, restrict is of text data type, and we are trying to get the result where the informationType = 'MEASURE' and accessScope = 'NONE' in the column  value of table, but getting cannot extract elements from a scalar

```
SELECT distinct u_id
FROM u_restrict u,
    jsonb_array_elements(u.restrict::jsonb) AS r,
    jsonb_array_elements(r->'informationType') AS ir,
    jsonb_array_elements(ir->'accessScope') AS ase
WHERE ase->>'accessScope' = 'NONE'
AND ir->>'informationType' = 'MEASURE';
```

But getting below error -

> cannot extract elements from a scalar
> SQL state: 22023

Could anyone please help to rewrite the query to get the desired result.

Comment: Please explain what the Oracle query is doing (ideally with some sample data). You can't expect that everybody knows both DBMS well enough. Note that the column in Postgres should be defined as `jsonb` in order to avoid casting every time you want to do something meaningful with the JSON value.

Comment: The error message means that you are trying to apply `jsonb_array_elements` on a JSON value that is not an array. Without seeing your input data this is impossible to answer.

Comment: `select * from jsonb_array_elements
    (jsonb '{"accessScope":"world"}' ->'accessScope'); ` 

try to run `select jsonb_typeof(
    jsonb '{"accessScope":["world", "yes"]}' ->'accessScope');`

Comment: Also, how do the JSON data in the table look?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but it looks like you don't need to turn the array into rows at all. You can apply a JSON path expression in the WHERE clause which might also remove the need to apply DISTINCT:

```
select u_id
from u_restrict u
where u.restrict::jsonb @? '$[*] ? (@.informationType == "MEASURE" && @.accessScope == "NONE")'
```

Comment: Typo in `@.accessScope = "NONE"` (should be `==`) otherwise a *correct* solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the logic of your Oracle query, this should be it.

```sql
SELECT distinct u_id
FROM u_restrict u
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(u.restrict::jsonb) l(r)
WHERE r ->> 'accessScope' = 'NONE' 
  AND r ->> 'informationType' = 'MEASURE';
```